# Open MP recursive task creation overhead

Tags: c, openmp

My program has some significant overhead when setting more than 4 threads. I get longer times when increasing the threads at >4. I am parallelizing a backtracking algorithm and stop the program when a solution is found.
My idea is to only create tasks when there is atleast two following nodes per node and only create as much tasks as there are available threads to run the algorithm recursively.

Also when using depth < maxDepth in the if statement

> if (followingNodes > 1 && depth < maxDepth)

I don't get a solution at all when computing larger problems.

```
double start_time;
int threadNum;

struct grid copyGrid(struct grid grid)
{
    size_t size = grid.size * grid.size * sizeof(int);
    int* cpy_sudoku = malloc(size);
    int* src_sudoku = grid.sudoku;
    memcpy(cpy_sudoku, src_sudoku, size);
    struct grid cpyGrid;
    cpyGrid.sudoku = cpy_sudoku;
    cpyGrid.size = grid.size;
    return cpyGrid;
}

int isSafe(struct grid g, int row, int col, int num)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= g.size - 1; x++)
        if (g.sudoku[row * g.size + x] == num)
            return 0;

    for (int x = 0; x <= g.size - 1; x++)
        if (g.sudoku[x * g.size + col] == num)
            return 0;

    int startRow = row - row % (int)sqrt(g.size),
        startCol = col - col % (int)sqrt(g.size);

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)sqrt(g.size); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < (int)sqrt(g.size); j++)
            if (g.sudoku[(startRow * g.size + i) + (j * g.size + startCol)] == num)
                return 0;

    return 1;
}

int solveSudoku(struct grid* grid, int row, int col, int depth, int maxDepth)
{
    int index = row * grid->size + col;

    if (row == grid->size - 1 && col == grid->size)
        return 1;

    if (col == grid->size)
    {
        row++;
        col = 0;
    }

    if (grid->sudoku[index] > 0)
        return solveSudoku(grid, row, col + 1, depth, maxDepth);

    num_queue* numsQueue = NULL;
    int followingNodes = 0;
    for (int num = 1; num <= grid->size; num++)
    {
        if (isSafe(*grid, row, col, num) == 1)
        {
            intEnqueue(&numsQueue, num);
            followingNodes++;
        }
    }
    int num;
    while ((num = intDequeue(&numsQueue, 1)) > 0)
    {
        grid->sudoku[index] = num;

        if (followingNodes > 1 && depth < maxDepth)
        {
            struct grid copiedGrid;
            #pragma omp critical
            copiedGrid = copyGrid(*grid);
            #pragma omp task firstprivate(copiedGrid,row,col,depth,maxDepth) shared(start_time)
            {
                if (solveSudoku(&copiedGrid, row, col + 1, depth + 1, maxDepth) == 1)
                {
                    double solutionTime = omp_get_wtime() - start_time;
                    printf("%f\n", solutionTime);
                    exit(0);
                }
                free(copiedGrid.sudoku);
            }

        }
        else if (solveSudoku(grid, row, col + 1, depth, maxDepth) == 1) // Compute serial
            return 1;
        followingNodes--;
    }
    grid->sudoku[index] = 0;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


    threadNum = atoi(argv[1]);
    char* file = argv[2];
    double startInit_time = omp_get_wtime();
    struct grid rootGrid = readGridFromFile(file);

    if (threadNum == 0)
        return 0;
    start_time = omp_get_wtime();
        #pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(rootGrid, threadNum) num_threads(threadNum)
        {
            #pragma omp single nowait
                solveSudoku(&rootGrid, 0, 0, 0, threadNum);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My suggestion is to first create a simple code which is working properly (even if a larger problem is computed). It is not worth talking about performance issues as long as your code is not correct. Is it working properly without OpenMP? If you create a [mre] which does not give a solution, we can help you to fix your code.

Comment: No allocator perfectly scale so having a malloc/free calls in a parallel section can cause the whole code not to scale. Using tasks and malloc/free that way should not be efficient on NUMA systems since data allocated/filled on 1 NUMA node can be read/written from another one causing NUMA overhead (eg. saturation of some NUMA memory node, additional latency). Not all OpenMP runtimes care about data locality in task scheduling: AFAIK GOMP (GCC) use a global centralized scheduling queue so far while IOMP (Clang/ICC) use a better NUMA-aware multi-queue approach.

Comment: Also note that new AMD CPUs (eg. Ryzen/ThreadReaper) generally has multiple NUMA nodes per socket so it matter on such systems (that are now quite common, even on PCs). Computing server generally has >=2 sockets so at least 2 NUMA nodes. Besides, I advise you to specify the target CPUs used for such question as well as the compiler/runtime (and possibly optimization flags).

Comment: @Laci so my code was not working properly because I had a typo here (solveSudoku(grid, row, col + 1, depth, maxDepth == 1)) which should be (solveSudoku(grid, row, col + 1, depth, maxDepth) == 1). But the performance issue stays. I use Visual studio and an AMD Ryzen CPU

Comment: Please post a complete code (e.g. like [this](https://askcodes.net/projects/sudoku-puzzle-game), which can be run after a copy/paste and we can check the performance issue. Is the `#pragma omp critical` line necessary? As mentioned by @JérômeRichard memory bound code may not scale well with the number of threads used.

Comment: Random comment: the fact that you have a `copygrid` function means that you should really learn C++. Even if there is no difference in performance, programming is a whole lot easier.

Comment: I think something is missing in your code: you create a bunch of tasks, but I don't see you aborting the futile ones once some other task has found a solution. See my solution of a slightly different problem. https://theartofhpc.com/pcse/omp-examples.html#Depth-firstsearch

Comment: @Laci no the omp critical is not necessary for copying the grid but doesnt change a lot. 
https://pastebin.pl/view/fe03348e

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Ive set the Environment variable in powershell (Is this right?) before executing the omp exe and I have pretty much the same results. I also have an MPI program which calculates far quicker results even though it uses the same backtracking algorithm. E.g. omp varies strongly with 1-23 secs and mpi very steady with 1.5-2.2 seconds to calculate the solution and then exit.

Comment: `sudoku_seriell.h` is missing

Comment: @Laci im sorry i forgot to delete the include line.

Comment: The problem is not an unnecessary include file, but parts of your code are still missing (e.g `num_queue` type) and it cannot be compiled: https://godbolt.org/z/7f11nb34P